# How to add tree view data into CSV file using csvhelper in c#

Tags: c#, csv, treeview, csvhelper

```
A >
    A1>
       A1.1
B
C
D
E>
  E1 
  E2
  E3 > 
      E3.1
      E3.2
```

CSV data

```
Names  internal core 
A.       A1.      A1.1
B
C
D
E.        E1
          E2
          E3.     E3.1
                  E3.2
```

Comment: What is the problem you encountered ?

Comment: What is the code you've been using so far?

Comment: you need to store the parent for each node. f.i. E => null, E3 => E, E3.1 => E3 and E3.2 => E3

Comment: Can somebody give me the c# code for this using CSVwriter